# Background Audio Player Memory Profiler Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to run memory profiler on my App (WP 8) which uses BackgroundAudio. But it seems to be working only on main thread. Is it possible to watch memory usage by Audio Agent?
There seems to be lack of information about this (or maybe I've looked for it not where I should). Do you know something about this?
Thank you in advance.